# Find the limit of $ x_n = \prod_{j=2}^{n} \left(1 - \frac{2}{j(j+1)}\right)^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Let $x_n=(1-\frac{1}{3})^2(1-\frac{1}{6})^2(1-\frac{1}{10})^2 \ldots...(1-\frac{1}{n(n+1)/2})^2, \text{where} \space n \geq 2$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=?$

I see that $x_n^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{2}{3}\frac{5}{6}\frac{9}{10} \ldots..\frac{(n-1)(n+2)}{n(n+1)}$. now not sure what to do next ?Any idea?

Comment: It converges, as $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n(n+1)/2}$ converges. So you want the value of the limit, I assume.

Comment: If you consider $y_n = \log x_n$ and use $\log(ab) = \log a + \log b$, I think you will get a telescoping series.

Comment: Converges to 1/3.

Comment: @julien: You will get $y_n = 2 \sum \ln(n-1) + 2 \sum \ln(n+2) - 2 \sum \ln n - 2 \sum \ln(n+1)$, so except for a few initial terms and last terms, each number appears twice with a $+2$ and twice with a $-2$.

Comment: @TMM Right, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to canncel out everything you have in your $\sqrt{x_n}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note you really have a telescoping product. To see this intuitively, write out a few terms. You start with $\frac{1 \cdot 4}{2 \cdot 3}$

$$\frac{1 \cdot 4}{2 \cdot 3} \times \frac{2 \cdot 5}{3 \cdot 4} = \frac{1 \cdot 5}{3 \cdot 3}$$

and adding another term

$$\frac{1 \cdot 5}{3 \cdot 3} \times \frac{3 \cdot 6}{4 \cdot 5} = \frac{1 \cdot 6}{3 \cdot 4}$$

and proceed by induction to prove that $x_n = \frac{1 \cdot (n+2)}{3 \cdot n}$ which in the limit should converge to 1/3.

Comment: Typo: the first $4$ should be a $3$ on line $2$. +1.

Comment: @julien Fixed thank you

Comment: Thanks for the detailed clarification.But I have one question. It is a multiple choice question where both options $1/3$ and $1/9$ are included.So what should be the right choice? As $x_n^{\frac{1}{2}} \to 1/3$ ,should $x_n$ tends to $1/9$ or $1/3?$

Comment: @learner: $\sqrt{x_n} \to 1/3$ so yes, $x_n \to (1/3)^2 = 1/9$.

Comment: @TMM thank you very much

Comment: @TMM thanks a lot.got it.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(n)=\frac{n-1}{n+1}$. Then show $$1-\frac{1}{n(n+1)/2} = \frac{f(n)}{f(n+1)}$$

Answer (score 5):

$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{j=2}^n\left(1-\frac2{j(j+1)}\right)
&=\prod_{j=2}^n\left(\frac{(j-1)(j+2)}{j(j+1)}\right)\\
&=\color{#00A000}{\prod_{j=2}^n\frac{j-1}{j}}
\color{#C00000}{\prod_{j=2}^n\frac{j+2}{j+1}}\\
&=\color{#00A000}{\frac1n}\color{#C00000}{\frac{n+2}{3}}\\
&=\frac13\frac{n+2}{n}
\end{align}
$$
Taking it to the limit, we get
$$
\prod_{j=2}^\infty\left(1-\frac2{j(j+1)}\right)=\frac13
$$
The product of the squares is the square of the product (to get the answer to the modified question).

Comment: nice approach.Thanks a lot sir.